# characters inserted after cursor firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a WYSIWYG editor.
At some point I need to change the cursor position.
For that purpose I use this code :

```js
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

The new position is the one expected.
However, when I start typing text, it appears after the cursor, and reversed.
For instance if I type `test` it appear like this `|tset`.

This bug occurs in Firefox 31.0, while it's working just fine in Chrome.
Do you know what could cause this bug and how to fix it ?

**Edit:**

I found how to fix it:
The problem came from the fact that the element `startNode` was not focused. The bug can be fixed like that :

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
$(startNode).focus();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Comment: why on earth would you reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: Because I need a WYSIWYG with a page system, like Google Docs, but I can't find anything light, and easily customizable.